# I can not deploy windows 11 in hyper-v

Tags: hyper-v, windows-11

Can i setup a virtual machine with windows 11? I tried it but it wont work. It doesn't have the right requirements but i gave the machine 12gb ram. 150 gb ssd. 4 cores processor. So I don't think that's the problem. Anyone that can help me?

Comment: You need a TPM and Secure Boot for Windows 11. Are these available to your hypervisor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes that was the problem. I had to designate "generation 2" in the setup under "Specify Generation" and check the secure boot in the setting. That solved it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).